Unable to unmarshal nested struct in golang
I'm trying to unmarshal Config struct but failing to do so. Can someone please tell me why it's not working?
go playground: https://go.dev/play/p/a8oHOLpm0em
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/BurntSushi/toml"
)

type Meta struct {
    config  Config   `toml:"config"`
    Include []string `toml:"include"`
    Exclude []string `toml:"exclude"`
}

type Config struct {
    Title   string   `toml:"title"`
    Include []string `toml:"include"`
    Exclude []string `toml:"exclude"`
}

var expected_data = `
include = ["README.md", "LICENSE"]
exclude = ["tests", "docs", "examples", "notebooks"]

[config]
include = ["README.md", "LICENSE"]
exclude = ["tests", "docs", "examples", "notebooks"]
title = "pytorch-forecasting"
`

func main() {

    modfile := Meta{}

    _ = toml.Unmarshal([]byte(expected_data), &modfile)

    fmt.Println("Top level Include: ", modfile.Include)
    fmt.Println("Top level Exclude: ", modfile.Exclude)

    fmt.Println("Include: ", modfile.config.Include)
    fmt.Println("Exclude: ", modfile.config.Exclude)
    fmt.Println("Title: ", modfile.config.Title)
}

